# Why are we interested in square-free words?

Tags: word-combinatorics

There is wikipedia page about [square-free words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word), and there are a lot of theorems about these words, and examples of infinite square-free words.

I am wondering: why are we interested in these words?

Are there real-life applications of these words? Why are square-free words more useful to consider than other words?

Comment: In any Wikipedia page, a good start for further research is consulting its references. Have you looked up the works listed there? Were none of them useful?

Comment: The study of pure mathematics is not usually motivated by real-life applications.

Comment: Real-life? Hmm, what is that? Is entertainment part of real life? Is entertainment of the mind part of entertainment?

Comment: Because there aren't any for most alphabets? It's a curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, take a moment to reflect. Is a word or a string one of the most important and most common entities in this world? What are the most basic properties of a word or string?

- its alphabet
- its length
- its sound
- its meaning
- its syntax or grammar
- its origin
- its usage as how to form sentences.
- hmm, does it repeat part of itself? Or never (square-free)?

It looks like the property of being square-free is almost a fundamental property of a word (or a phrase, or a sentence).

In fact, it is amazing to me that the formal study of square-free words has not made it way into most of textbooks about the theory of automata and computation. It appears that the study of square-free words turns out to be a rather isolated field with less impact.

Nevertheless, the study of square-free words and related concepts is interesting and [fruitful](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=%22square-free+words%22), as you have observed. I am, for one, charmed by the square-free words of infinite length over three letters [1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/98648/91753).

"Real-life" application related to square-free words are sparse indeed. *Abelian square-free words in algorithmic music* by Laakso, T. might count as one; however, I cannot find that paper. (Gefwert, C., Orponen, P., Seppänen, J. (eds.) *Logic, Mathematics and the Computer*, vol. 14, pp. 292–297. Finnish Artificial Intelligence Society, Symposiosarja, Hakapaino, Helsinki).

---

Here are two related exercise to entertain your mind.

An abelian square is a subsequence of the form $s_1s_2$ where $s_2$ is a permutation of $s_1$. For example, $abcbac$ is an abelian square since $bac$ is a permutation of $abc$.

**Exercise 1.** (easy) Let the alphabet consist of 3 letters. Show a word of length 7 that is free of abelian square. Show that every word of length eight contains an abelian square.

**Exercise 2.** (very very hard) There is an infinite abelian-square-free word over an alphabet of size four.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I like this persepective a lot and it makes more sens to me why we care about square-free words. Also thank you for the exercises !  I think I have a solution for the first one : the word : **abacaba** is of length $7$ and is free abelian. Now let's suppose by contradiction that we found a free abelian word $v$ of length $8$ over the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$. Then if we write $v = xy$ where $\mid x \mid = \mid y \mid = 4$ then it means that there is a letter in $x$ that is not in $y$ or the contrary. But then $x$ or $y$ is only made of $2$ distincts letters.

Comment: This is impossible since every word of length $4$ over an alphabet of length $2$ is clearly never free-abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Under [related concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word#Related_concepts) on the wiki page for square-free we find the notion of cube-free words. An example of such words is the (Prouhet-)Thue-Morse sequence. Which has a very [real-life application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence#History).

> The sequence has been discovered independently many times, not always by professional research mathematicians; for example, Max Euwe, a chess grandmaster, who held the World Championship title from 1935 to 1937, and mathematics teacher, discovered it in 1929 in an application to chess: by using its cube-free property (see above), he showed how to circumvent a rule aimed at preventing infinitely protracted games by declaring repetition of moves a draw.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is indeed a nice application.